# Show Message within LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to show a standard message like "No Data to Display" in the below component when No record is found.[image]

```
    @wire(LeadSearchController, { currentId: '$recordId'})   
leadWrapperList({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.ledData = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.ledData = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        window.console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should import [ShowToastEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation):

```
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
```

Then fire the event to show message whenever needed:

```
if (data) {
        this.ledData = data;
        if (data && data.length === 0) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Get Help',
                    message: 'Salesforce documentation is available in the app. Click ? in the upper-right corner.',
                    variant: 'info'
                })
            );
        }
        this.error = undefined;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and time. However ShowToast doesn't meet my requirement. If my apex controller doesn't return any value then a message should be displayed saying for example "No Data to Display" and this message should be there until if any data is returned from Apex.